# Create multilingual website with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, multilingual

I'm new to coding, and I'm trying to create a multilingual website. So I've found the following implementation to be working:

JS

```
let langs = document.querySelector(".langs"),
     link = document.querySelectorAll("a"),
     lgmenu = document.querySelector(".lgmenu");
     lglanguage = document.querySelector(".lglanguage");

link.forEach(el=>{
     el.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
          langs.querySelector(".active").classList.remove("active");
          el.classList.add("active");

          let attr = el.getAttribute("language")

          lgmenu.textContent = data[attr].lgmenu
          lglanguage.textContent = data[attr].lglanguage

     })

})

let data = {
     romanian: {
          lgmenu: "Meniu",
          lglanguage: "Alege limba"
     },
     english: {
          lgmenu: "Menu",
          lglanguage: "Choose language"
     }
}


window.localStorage.setItem("langs", "romanian");
window.localStorage.setItem("langs", "english");
window.localStorage.getItem('langs');
```

My questions:

1. How to save the user's language selection? So the language won't reset on refresh or navigating between pages. I've read that I have to do it with localStorage. But I have no idea how to do this.
2. How to show the currently selected language in the header bar?
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEUQq.jpg

If you can please advise. Many thanks

Best regards,
Veaceslav

Answer (score 0):

1. To set any value to localStorage, simply do:

   ```
   localStorage.setItem('key', value);
   ```

   To retrieve the value, do:

   ```
   window.localStorage.getItem('key');
   ```
2. Add a script to retrieve the value and set an element's innerHTML equal to that value.

[More details on local storage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp)

Comment: Hi. I did like this - localStorage.setItem("langs", "romanian");
localStorage.setItem("langs", "english");
localStorage.getItem('langs');

Comment: But it's not working. What I'm missing? Thank you

Comment: @FrontPower, what is not working?

Comment: The selected language is not saved on refresh

Comment: @FrontPower could you add a link or edit the question including the code so far?

Comment: Sure, I've updated the original post. Thanks